# You will get stab by the needle

Tags: grammar

I saw the needle and wanted to play with it.

> "Don't play with the needle. You'll hurt yourself."
>
> "Don't play with the needle. You will get **stab** by the needle."

Is stab used correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's actually not correct at all. Firs of all, it should be ***you will get stabbed***. And secondly, with the verb ***get***, we always use past participles. Those are the forms of verbs that end in "ed". They're kind of like verb-based adjectives, if you will.

Comment: Is it also correct to say: *You will get a stab* ?

Comment: Grammatically speaking, yes.

Comment: So, I guess *you will get stabbed* is more natural or idiomatic than *you will get a stab*, right?

Comment: I guess so, but that all depends on context. You do not say "stabbed by a needle". "prick with a needle" sounds better. You stab someone with a knife.

Comment: "You will get a stab" more likely means you will get an opportunity to stab somebody else rather than somebody will stab you.